# Where do I find my Criteo Endpoint?

Tags: ads, endpoint, double-click, endpoints, criteo

I need to get my Criteo endpoints values from my account.

And I need them in order to use Criteo API and get ads on my placements.
Any ideas where can I get them ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to e-mail your designated point of contact at Criteo, they should be able to help you with integration. You can also try browsing their [API support pages](http://%20https://support.criteo.com/hc/en-us/articles/210162145-How-can-I-manually-generate-an-API-for-my-account-) to get familiarized with the process.

Update from 2021: The new developer portal is available here: https://developers.criteo.com/